# SI4T Custom Indexer never gets its addItemToIndex called

Tags: si4t

I'm writing a custom indexer for SI4T - I've captured a package representing the publish of a page from Tridion and am using it locally to test against my Deployer set-up in Eclipse.

My local Deployer is publishing to the same Broker db (using the SI4T **JPASearchDAOFactory**) as our DEV env where we setup the SI4T TBBs.

My problem is that even though I've unpublished my test page and I can see its removal from Broker before each test run, every time I drag/drop the test package into my local incoming folder, SI4T **always** treats it as an update - as my `updateItemInIndex` method is always triggered.

The [JPASearchDAOFactory](https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/master/storage-extensions/src/main/java/com/tridion/storage/si4t/dao/JPASearchPageDAO.java) seems to set `FactoryAction.UPDATE` in both create and update implementations - is that correct - is the intention to treat adds and updates as the same?

It would explain why I never see my `addItemToIndex` called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct. Essentially, a Page Update is always done by the underlying JPA implementation as an `JPASearchPageDAO.update`, followed by a `JPASearchPageDAO.create`, so in essence both are doing the same things. This has got me stuck quite a while when I was building this as well.

If you want to change that behaviour because you have to do extra stuff while creating pages, you could do something like this:

```java
@Component("JPASearchPageDAO")
@Scope("prototype")
public class JPASearchPageDAO extends JPAPageDAO implements PageDAO
{
    private String storageId;
    // Let's keep track of this DAO
    private boolean isUpdating = false;

    public void create(CharacterData page, String relativePath) throws StorageException
    {
        FactoryAction action = FactoryAction.CREATE

        if (!this.isUpdating)
        {
            /**
             * Do creation specific stuff here, or in the Factory, since we've now set
             * the action to CREATE.
             */ 


        }
        else
        {
            action = FactoryAction.UPDATE
        }

        log.debug("Create.");
        TridionPublishableItemProcessor tp;
        try
        {
            tp = new TridionPublishableItemProcessor(
                    page.getString(),
                    action,
                    IndexType.PAGE,
                    Integer.toString(page.getPublicationId()),
                    "tcm:" + page.getPublicationId() +"-" + page.getId() + "-64"
                    , this.storageId);
            CharacterData c = tp.processPageSource(page);
            if (c != null)
            {
                super.create(c, relativePath);
            }
            else
            {
                log.error("Error processing page: " + relativePath + ", proceeding with deployment of original page");
                super.create(page, relativePath);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            log.error(Utils.stacktraceToString(e.getStackTrace()));
            throw new StorageException("IO Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
        }
    }


    // Note: An update triggers a create always.
    @Override
    public void update(CharacterData page, String originalRelativePath, String newRelativePath) throws StorageException
    {
        this.isUpdating = true;

        // ... 
    }
}
```

Now that I think of it, I'll add this fix in the next release of SI4T as well. :)

Comment: Thanks Raimond. My point was more that the SI4T documentation should probably be updated to highlight that the current implementation won't trigger addItemToIndex even though its a part of the "documented" interface.